# as/400 ascii - equivalent Encoding in .NET

Tags: encoding, character-encoding

What would be the Encoding in .Net that is equivalent to IBM AS/400 ASCII ? 
 What i the System.Text.Encoding()? Is System.Text.Encoding.ASCII 100% compatible with IBM AS/400 ASCII?

Comment: Are you sure the AS/400 in question is using ASCII (or some superset thereof)? Some use EBCDIC instead...

Comment: thts what the guy told me - maybe he doesn't know, i will ask him, nice hint